# Get month name from php timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have a table which stores a php timestamp as a interger. I need to access this data by date and year. I can grab the year and match it with a column row that exists within the table but need to obtain the month name from the timestamp.

Code so far

```
$query="SELECT * FROM archive_agent_booking
    WHERE agent_id='$account_no'
    AND (MONTHNAME(comp_date)='$month' AND year='$year' AND details='')
    ORDER BY order_time";
```

unfortunately this is returning nothing.

`comp_date` is the column that contains the timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert it to date first using `FROM_UNIXTIME`

```
MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(comp_date)) = '$month'
```

- [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks - and thanks for the extra information. I use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the inputted variables - will this avoid any mysqli injection attempts ?

Comment: but still be careful with that: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wrap it in [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert it first to a MySQL `DATETIME` which is needed by `MONTHNAME()`

```
AND MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(comp_date)) = '$month'
```

If you are early enough in this project to change direction a little, I would recommend storing the value as a proper `DATETIME` type instead of the int value Unix timestamp.  MySQL is better able to handle date types natively without having to convert in and out with `UNIX_TIMESTMAP(), FROM_UNIXTIME()` all the time.

We assume your value `$month` is properly escaped if it originates from user input. Otherwise, consider switching to an API which supports prepared statements like MySQLi or PDO.